# Find final square in matrix walking like a spiral

Tags: matrices

Given the matrix `A x A` and a number of movements `N`.

And walking like a spiral:

1. right while possible, then
2. down while possible, then
3. left while possible, then
4. up while possible, repeat until got `N`.

Image with example (`A = 8; N = 36`)

[image]

In this example case, the final square is `(4; 7)`.

My question is: Is it possible to use a generic formula to solve this?

Comment: Do you mean to ask whether there is a closed-form expression for both the row and the column of the last square?

Comment: @BrianTung. Actually, (`A = 8; N = 36`) are very very low numbers. The closest I can get to `N` would be nice.

Comment: Well, whether or not there's a closed-form expression isn't affected by how large the numbers are.

Comment: @Sorry I don't have a simple hint to give for your question (I deleted my answer because I misread it). But almost certainly you need the absolute value function, the floor function and square-roots (possibly modulo) because it's somewhat quadratic behaviour.

Comment: Thank you guys.. I got one solution here: _http://stackoverflow.com/a/33575439/4227915_